# When I am submitting my topology to storm, i am getting an error from "lein"

Tags: apache-storm, leiningen, topology

I am trying to submit my topology to storm:

> sparse submit

Virtual environment is creating successfully and also "lean clean" is successfully is done.
But, when it trying to create a jar,

> lein jar <*topology*>

it is giving me an error "Failed to create jar"

I have check in my system, lein is successfully installed and inside "project.clj" the version numbers are proper.

And this error is appearing only when I am submitting my topology to storm.
Even I checked my topology, spout and bolt code, there are no error in it.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE1jW.png)

Comment: can you also share error stack trace with the versions you are using?

Comment: I am using lein 2.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streamparse doesn't work with the latest version of Lein. I was having the same issue and I down graded Lein to 2.7.1.
It works perfectly for me.

Comment: As you mentioned, I edited "lein" file and changed " export LEIN_VERSION="2.9.1" " to " export LEIN_VERSION="2.7.1" ". then ran the file and worked for me. Thank you very much.